# Let D = ${[ x\in R^2 :|x|\leq1}]$ Is there any onto, Continuous function from D to X. Where X = [-1 , 1]

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Let D = ${[ x\in R^2 :|x|\leq1}]$.Is there any on-to,continuous function from D to X. Where X = [-1 , 1]

My Attempt :
If I take an interior point $(y)$ in the interval whose pre-image is in the circle $(x)$ and exclude these two points from their domains we will get the domain D is still connected but the range set is not connected and function will remain continuous.

So there does not exist.
Am I right?

Comment: You have asked 3 questions in a two hours time interval. Take the time to breath, and to work by yourself.

Comment: @JeanMarie I got rewarded for this also... I got downvoted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just project onto the x-axis, by $f(x, y) = x$

Comment: Can u please tell me where I was wrong in my logic?@B. Mehta

Comment: If you exclude $(x)$ from $D$, there could still be another point $(x')$ in $D$ that maps to $(y)$, keeping the range connected.

Comment: ohhh..If it was One to One instead of onto my attempt would have been correct..Is not it?@B. Mehta

Comment: Yes, exactly, that argument would then work.

Comment: so what do u do? Where do u live?@B. Mehta

Comment: It seems U don't want to make personal conversation with me.. But u helped me a lot..bahat shukriya...@B. Mehta

Answer (score 2):

Sure, 
$$ x\mapsto \sin2\pi|x|.$$

Comment: Can u please tell me where I was wrong in my logic?

Comment: @sani Your logic seems to assume that the function is injective. After removing one $x$ that maps to $y$, there may still be other points that map to $y$

Comment: My function was unnecessarily complicated by the way cause I assumed the question was about the *open* disk to the *closed* interval :)